# How to fix "Range.Find Return null" Problem in C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I have a C# code using an Excel file, that includes some part numbers. when I search manually, I can find mentioned item, but when I use the code, it can not find in worksheet, and find method returns null.

my code is as below ...

```
currentFind = null;
firstFind = null;

Excel.Range part_number = WH1_Sheet.UsedRange;
currentFind = part_number.Find(PN, missing,
    Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
    Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false,
    missing, missing);
```